# Переделать RegExp под старый синтаксис

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть функция, которая принимает строку, и добавляет в массив только те значения, которые соответствуют регулярному выражению. ( Возвращает только подстроки, которые начинаются с хэштега, длина которых либо 3, либо 6 символов. То есть такие как #abc или #AA00ef). RegExp который я использую работает, но мне надо переписать его под синтаксис ES6, то есть без использования LookAhead.

```
function getHexadecimalColors(str) {
    let res = [];
    return str.match(/(?<=#)[0-9a-f]{6}|(?<=#)[0-9a-f]{3}(?![0-9a-f])/ig);
}
```

Comment: Не получится, по-моему. Если добавлять захват, то будет уже совсем другой принцип парсинга. Вместо этого, просто отрезай "хэштег" у результатов: `str.match(/#(?:[0-9a-f]{6}|[0-9a-f]{3}(?![0-9a-f]))/ig).map(v => v.slice(1))` - это самое близкое к исходному варианту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте захватывающую подмаску:

```js
/#([0-9a-f]{3}(?:[0-9a-f]{3})?)(?![0-9a-f])/ig
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/oNS4gz/1). *Подробности**:

- `#` - символ `#`
- `([0-9a-f]{3}(?:[0-9a-f]{3})?)` - три символа, используемых для обозначения шестнадцатеричных чисел, и затем ещё три таких символа (если есть)
- `(?![0-9a-f])` - сразу после текущей позиции не должно быть символа, используемого для обозначения шестнадцатеричных чисел.

Пример кода:

```js
function getHexadecimalColors(str) {
    var res = [],
      re = /#([0-9a-f]{3}(?:[0-9a-f]{3})?)(?![0-9a-f])/ig,
      m;
    while (m = re.exec(str)) {
      res.push(m[1]);
    }
    return res;
}

console.log(getHexadecimalColors('То есть такие как #abc или #AA00ef)'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, цвета могут быть ещё в 4 и 8 знаков (альфаканал) - возможно, их тоже стоит добавить.

```js
function getHexadecimalColors(str) {
  var res = str.match(/#([0-9a-f]{3}|[0-9a-f]{6})(?![0-9a-f])/gi)
  return res && res.map(function (x) { return x.slice(1) });
}

console.log(getHexadecimalColors("a #12eq ##eeeeee#ff8#fffqqq#000abc#fff6"))
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, действительно. Оказывается, в ES6 только флаги добавили. Поправил.